# Get public url of File in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

What is the proper way to get absolute url of an image in backend module context in TYPO3 11?
For my $file record (TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\File) I can run following

```
$file->getOriginalResource()->getPublicUrl()
```

and then I will get relative path of the image.
Then I can get public base for the site by this:

```
$siteFinder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SiteFinder::class);
$site = current($siteFinder->getAllSites());
$site->getBase();
```

and at the end concatenate both as below:

```
$absoluteImageUrl = $site->getBase(). $file->getOriginalResource()->getPublicUrl();
```

But is there maybe better or more elegant way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use the `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\ImageService` for this.

```
$absoluteImageUrl = $this->imageService->getImageUri(
   $file->getOriginalResource(),
   true
);
```

The first argument has to be an instance of `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileInterface`, the second argument is a flag indicating if the URL should be absolute (default: `false`).